# Why compareTo doesn't return result using dates

Tags: java

I have dates in String format as "yyyyMMdd"
I converted them to Dates using these two function :

The first one is converting "yyyyMMdd" to "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
private static String converteDate(String inputString) {

        SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        String reformattedStr = null;
        try {
            reformattedStr = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(inputString));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return reformattedStr;
    }
```

The second function is converting the "yyyy-MM-dd" to date type:

```
public static Date convertToDate(String receivedDate) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = formatter.parse(receivedDate);
    return date;
}
```

Then I need to get a sorting of dates using comparaison between dates, So I used CompareTo Function :

```
public int compareTo(Personne personne) {
        int res = 0;
        Personne other = personne;
        // Conversion of Dates from String to Dates

        Date otherDate = null;
        try {
            otherDate = convertToDate(other.getDA_PRM_CTR_ORDER());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Date entreePersonne = null;
        try {
            entreePersonne = convertToDate(this.DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        res = entreePersonne.compareTo(otherDate);

return res;
}
```

This is doesn't work and it returns this

> Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable) line: not available

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsCQ5.png)

EDIT :

As @MLem said

When I debugg it doesn't convert to date fomrat et pass to the exception :

[this the given trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkf91.png)

It's really weird because the function convertToDate retun the date format normally.

Comment: In several occasions you do a try-catch to just print the stacktrace and then completly ignore the exception and continue your program flow as if it never happened. A very bad idea. That creates a lot of potential NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson, in fact the program oblige me to do them . It show me this error `Unhandled exception type ParseException` if I do not try/cash and it propose quick fix

Comment: That "quick fix" is no fix. As I said it simply ignores the exception and continues as if it didn't happen. You need to really handle the exceptions.

Comment: And you should stop using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. They're declared obsolete a long time ago and supplanted by the newer Java Date and Time API, available in the `java.time` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a NullPointerException, look at the stack trace to know where it occurs.

Note that your try/catch are hazardous, if an exception is thrown, your otherDate or entreePersonne variables will be null, which is one possible cause of your NullPointerException.

Your compareTo(Personne) should throws ParseException, or have a documented behavior in case a date is unparseable.

EDIT :
I noticed after your edit that you don't use your converteDate method, so you have an input date in yyyyMMdd format and you try to parse it with yyyy-MM-dd format, hence the ParseException.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something like other said :
your string are unparseable, so it throw silented ParseException.
Your variable are still null, no calling a method on them will throw NullPointerException.
Try to answer this : what should you do if you can't parse given string ? Do it in catch block.